# MonoTouch: "Missing a required architecture armv7"

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store

After updating to MonoTouch 5.2.4 and submitting an app to the App store, it was rejected by the App Loader because:

> "iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture. At
>   least one of the following architectures(s) must be present: armv7"

Is there a way around this in MonoTouch?

Comment: I had the same problem too, I fixed it by simply enabling LLVM with ARMv7 in the Advanced tab of the iPhone Build section of the project's options. I'm adding a comment because i don't really qualify this as an answer because it's just a quick fix, I'd like to know a real fix too.

Comment: Should I add ARMv6 too? to support older iPhone 3 ?

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Xamarin

Comment: What iOS versions are you targeting? This dictates which hardware platforms you need to support.

Comment: Adding both ARMs in the build properties seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To satisfy Apple's architecture requirements for the iPad you can either use:

- the LLVM option and select ARMv7 (no need for ARMv6 when the application is for the iPad only); or
- add a `--armv7` to the **Additional mtouch arguments**. This won't be using the LLVM compiler (but the regular Mono AOT compiler) but will produce some (not much) ARMv7 assembly.

Using LLVM will produce smaller and faster code but it will take a lot more time to build the application (that's not generally an issue for releasing to the appstore). OTOH you cannot use this option for debugging (again not really an issue for the appstore builds).

> Should I add ARMv6 too? to support older iPhone 3 ?

Apple's message indicates you're building an **iPad-only** application. If it's not the case then you need to change this (to allow iPhones, iPod Touch) and not the ARM-CPU selection (using only ARMv6 is ok when you target older devices).

Comment: I forced the app to have both ARMs as it's a Universal app. Once I did that it works. I submitted a bug to Xamarin as we've never needed to set the ARM before.

Comment: I think apple made this requirement *more* important lately (it's getting a more popular request). However I'm surprised by the message... anyway an universal application with both ARMv6 and ARMv7 will be optimal for both older and newer devices (but a lot larger since it will have 2 binaries merged together).